# What is best way to call PostgreSQL function from CodeIgniter

Tags: postgresql, function, codeigniter, parameters

I am using CodeIgniter 3.0.6 and PostgreSQL 9.4. I have a PostgreSQL function with some 4 parameters, out of 4 parameters 3 are string and one is of type bit. I have used the following method to call my function

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_function('$param1', '$param2', '$param_bit', '$param4')";

return $this->db->query($query);
```

the above method works fine for me, but for security reasons I have decided to use query binding so the values are automatically escaped. I tried the following method

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_function(?, ?, ?, ?)";

return $this->db->query($query, $param1, $param2, $param_bit, $param4);
```

but is shows
ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1

So I tries a different methods,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_function('?', '?', '?', '?')";

return $this->db->query($query, $param1, $param2, $param_bit, $param4);
```

but it shows No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_function(?::varchar, ?::varchar, ?::bit, ?::varchar)";

return $this->db->query($query, $param1, $param2, $param_bit, $param4);
```

but it shows ERROR: syntax error at or near "::" LINE 1:

Even tried with quotes and datatypes, but none of them worked for me.

If anyone ever worked before with PostgreSQL functions with parameters, please share how it can be done.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you use `cast(? As varchar)` instead of `?::varchar` ?

Comment: Clement Thanks for your reply, I tried, but its not working showing this error ERROR: syntax error at or near "As"